# How to connect a draft to the message that is sent from it

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an app which create drafts for a user, which the user can then manually send.

I'm trying to check whether a given draft has been sent but I can't see a good way of connecting a draft id to a sent id.

I believe when a draft is sent, the draft is deleted, and a copy is created in SentItems, so I can subscribe to SentItems, and see the sent message, but I can't confirm which draft the sent message is connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the ImmutableId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id . When the draft message is moved to sentItems folder the ImmutableId should be the same. (Drafts aren't deleted they are just moved but if you don't use ImmutableId's the Id of the message will always change).

Another option if you don't want to use ImmutableId's is use the pidtagSearchKey https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsearchkey-canonical-property that property shouldn't change when the item is moved or you could create your own extended property and the search for that once the message has been sent.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a downside to immutable-ids at all? Doesn't seem to mention 1 in the docs.

Comment: There is no downside to using them, the Search endpoint doesn't return them which i logged a bug against a while ago.